# How can I know cURL is sending on multipart/form-data?

Tags: php, curl

I am writing a cURL with PHP without specifying the Content-type in the header, I set the post fields as below and it works. My question is how do I know if it is sent by multipart/form-data or not?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST) );
```

Comment: from what I know if you send them like this, as urlencoded string for sure the enctype is not `multipart/form-data`, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 2):

**CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**

> If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. 
>   If value is a string, like in your code, Content-Type will be set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

[Source](http://php.net/curl_setopt)

You can see request headers by following code:

```
$request_headers = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
var_dump($request_headers);
```